# Fit line segments to shape

Tags: python, optimization, model-fitting, scipy-optimize-minimize

Suppose I have a binary image as shown below. The white colour indicates the shape of interest.

[image]

Task: I want to fit two connected line segment that best describes the shape. Example output is shown below.

[image]

Constraints: We can assume that the start, mid and end points are all part of the white shape and are integers.

What I have tried so far:
I tried scipy.optimize.minimize but it seems to be stuck in a local minimum and I cannot constrain the search space to be an integer and be one of the white coordinates. I also tried basinhopping which seems to give good results but it takes forever to run and I don't know how to constrain the solution as per above.

```
import scipy.optimize as spo

def fit_skeleton(start_point, mid_point, end_point, data_points):
"""

:param start_point: np.array,
    an array of shape (1,2) representing the x,y coordinates of the start point.
:param mid_point: np.array,
    an array of shape (1,2) representing the x,y coordinates of the start point.
:param end_point: np.array,
    an array of shape (1,2) representing the x,y coordinates of the start point.
:param data_points: np.array,
    an array of shape (n,2) representing the list of x,y coordinates of the pixels of the shape in the image. 
:return: 
"""
    start_point_x, start_point_y = start_point
    mid_point_x, mid_point_y = mid_point
    end_point_x, end_point_y = end_point
    result = spo.basinhopping(objective_function,
                          x0=[start_point_x, start_point_y, mid_point_x, mid_point_y, end_point_x, end_point_y],
                          minimizer_kwargs={"args": (data_points,)},
                          stepsize=1,
                          accept_test=mybounds
                          )
    start_point_x, start_point_y, mid_point_x, mid_point_y, end_point_x, end_point_y = result.x
```

The objective function simply measures the distance the shape's pixels from the closest line segment and sums these. The objective function is fine. I just want to know if there is a simple and quick approach that can find the two line segments that best fit the shape given the constraints.

Comment: Interesting problem. Could you please provide your objective function and some example data points? :) In the meantime, I think you need to formulate your problem as a mixed-integer (nonlinear) programming problem if you are interested in a global optimum.